# Date.now in passport.js cannot be done

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, passport.js

I want to assign registerdate when I create a user via facebook in my nodejs website. I'm using passport.
If I use local provider it is possible in my Mongoose Schema to use

```
regisDate: {
    type:Date,
    'default': Date.now
  },
```

however in passport facebook this is my code:

```
function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    User.findOne({'facebook.id': profile.id}).exec()
      .then(user => {
        if (user) {
          return done(null, user);
        }

        user = new User({

          firstName: profile.first_name,
          lastName: profile.last_name,
          address: '',
          regisDate: Date.now,
          birthday: profile.birthday,

          email: profile.emails[0].value,
          role: 'user',
          provider: 'facebook',
          facebook: profile._json
        });
        user.save()
          .then(user => done(null, user))
          .catch(err => done(err));
      })
      .catch(err => done(err));
  }));
```

and when proceed it returning an error in page like this.

```
ValidationError: CastError: Cast to Date failed for value "function now() { [native code] }" at path "regisDate"
   at MongooseError.ValidationError (/home/gema/Desktop/stash/tx/node_modules/mongoose/lib/error/validation.js:22:11)
   at model.Document.invalidate (/home/gema/Desktop/stash/tx/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:1411:32)
   at model.Document.set (/home/gema/Desktop/stash/tx/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:696:10)
   at model.Document.set (/home/gema/Desktop/stash/tx/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:541:18)
   at model.Document (/home/gema/Desktop/stash/tx/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:67:10)
   at model.Model (/home/gema/Desktop/stash/tx/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:41:12)
   at new model (/home/gema/Desktop/stash/tx/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:3200:11)
   at passport.js:24:16
From previous event:
   at model.wrappedPointCut [as save] (/home/gema/Desktop/stash/tx/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:1893:14)
   at passport.js:37:14
   at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:534:15)
   at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:514:5)
From previous event:
   at Strategy._verify (passport.js:19:8)
   at /home/gema/Desktop/stash/tx/node_modules/passport-oauth2/lib/strategy.js:193:24
   at /home/gema/Desktop/stash/tx/node_modules/passport-facebook/lib/strategy.js:181:5
   at passBackControl (/home/gema/Desktop/stash/tx/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:125:9)
   at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/gema/Desktop/stash/tx/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:143:7)
   at emitNone (events.js:85:20)
   at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:179:7)
   at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:913:12)
   at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
   at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
```

How to call Date.now function properly via passport ?
thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Date.now` is a function, you should use it this way: `Date.now()` if you want to get a timestamp

Comment: Hey, thanks ! anyway I've got another weird solution that I didn't notice. So I declare in my users.model schema that regisDate: {type: Date, 'default': Date.now} it works though. Therefore I wouldn't have to put it in my passport.js